# Visual Studio 2012 will not save/overwrite read only files

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

So, up until I installed VS2012, when I tried to edit a read only file in VS2010, a dialog popped up giving me three options when I pressed Save:

- Edit in memory
- Make writable
- Save a copy

Suddenly, it has stopped offering these options. Is there a way to put it back without popping up the save dialog every time and then telling me the file is read only.

I think this maybe source control related but the projects I'm using is not bound within the IDE to source control, just that the file is in source control

Comment: FFS! If you want to close questions explain yourselves

Comment: I almost downvoted. Please don't make me read the linked posts!

Comment: @Jon: The one close vote so far is for migrating to SuperUser, which seems somewhat appropriate given that you're talking about tool usage (Visual Studio) and registry settings.  You could also do well to improve the question by bringing over the relevant content from the linked questions.  Each question (and answer) should be fully self-sustaining and not require a link in order to be usable.

Comment: I've seen this happen when used with a source control system that doesn't play nicely with the IDE.  Are you using any type of source control?

Comment: What @David said, I was just too lazy to say it.

Comment: @Jeremy yes but its not bound with the IDE

Comment: @Jon: Not to drag on a comment thread, but I can click on the `Close` option and see the existing close votes without committing one of my own.

Comment: But the first sentence is "edit a read only file in VS2010".   That implies IDE bound.

Comment: You mentioned in your original question that you've tried the registry hack.  Seeing as you are using VS2012, are you certain you are modifying the proper key?  You reference to the question (in your original question) indicated an older version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Not sure, if there are new keys how do I find them

Comment: Flagged to reopen. Visual Studio questions are incredibly on-topic. Notice that the Visual Studio tag has been applied to over 34k questions.

Comment: I have been running VS2012 for a short while, and this functionality worked exactly as I expected, until I installed the 'Visual Studio Tools for Git' from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c

Comment: I mainly use Perforce but even after I set the Source Control Plugin back to P4VS, the new behaviour of dis-allowing saving to read-only files regardless of the setting in VS2012

Answer (score 20):

Rather than hack the registry I simply selected "None" in the Tools>>Options>>Source Control>>Plug-in Selection.

Comment: Yep, this works. The Git SCM plugin is what breaks this functionality.

Comment: This also happens with Jazz plugin.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same problem with Visual Studio 2013.  I solved the problem by editing the registry:

- Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\SourceControlProviders
- Remove the key dealing with GitSccProvider

Not sure why this works.  I figured it may have something to do with source-control integration given this persons post at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4e4c1878-3901-425e-a454-2c0d628275b0/when-saving-a-modified-readonly-file-it-always-pops-up-save-as-dialog?forum=vseditor where he solved the problem by disabling a Mercurial plugin.

Comment: As an aside, why have I got this extension? I can't see it listed and never use GIT so I'd have no reason to have installed it?

Comment: No need to remove it completely; simply deselect it in the options as per accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the settings checkbox:

`Tools | Options... | Environment | Documents`

- Allow editing of read-only files; warn when attempt to save

Comment: This setting is always overridden by whatever source control provider is active. So it only works if you set the source control plugin to "None" as per the answer from @TheArtTrooper

Comment: Fixed the issue for me without messing around in the registry.

Comment: Unfortunately, re donovan's answer, I have a source control plug-in, but I am editing files outside of the solution.  So the plug-in can't check it out.  All I want to do is edit. :(

Answer (score 3):

in Tools->Options->Source Control  Current source control plug-in Select None.
and the problem will be solved

Comment: Thanks! Perforce suddenly, on it's own initiative, decided to enable the perforce plugin on my visual studio, causing massive frustration!

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2012 the registry key has changed slightly.  The new key is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\SourceControl\AllowUncontrolledInMemoryEditing
```

Setting the value to 0 will give you the dialog you are used to seeing.

Comment: This is tied into Michael Burr's answer, it sets this reg value but it still doesnt allow me to save the file without it popping up the save dialog

Answer (score 0):

You may also find [this extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/146b404a-3c91-46ff-932a-fb0f8b826f94) useful as it makes sure the GIT source control is turned off everytime a solution is loaded.